# Convert int MMDDYYYY into datetime MM-DD-YYYY

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, type-conversion, sqldatatypes

**I would like to 
convert int MMDDYYYY (e.g.-5112012) into datetime MM-DD-YYYY 
and then convert datetime MM-DD-YYYY into YYYY-MM-DD**
or if the above can be done in one step converting int MMDDYYYY into datetime YYYY-MM-DD?

For reference, earlier I converted int YYYYMMDD into datetime YYYY-MM-DD using the following syntax:

```
declare @date int;
set @date = 19900511
select CONVERT(datetime, convert(varchar(8),@date), 103)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @date INT;
SET @date = 5112012
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @date), 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING( '0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @date), 3, 2) + '-' + RIGHT(@date,4))
```

That bails the water, now fix the leak; change the storage from int to a proper date or datetime :)

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @date int
set @date = 19900511
select CONVERT(CHAR(10), CONVERT(datetime, convert(varchar(8),@date), 103), 21)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/334)

The result is **1990-05-11**

Answer (score -1):

```
convert( datetime, 
  case when @MMDDYYYY = 0 then 
    null 
  else 
    substring(convert( varchar(9), 800000000 + @MMDDYYYY ) , 2, 2) 
               + '/' +  substring(
                   convert( varchar(9), 800000000 + @MMDDYYYY ) , 4, 2) 
               + '/' + right(@MMDDYYYY,4) end ) as New_Date
```